# return dynamically allocated 2D array in struct in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, data-structures, 2d

I'm trying to return a dynamically allocated 2d array from a function, there are no errors or warnings but the numbers are wrong when printing them at the end. If someone can tell me where I messed up Im sure its something obvious.

this is a simplified version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rows = 2, cols=2 ;

struct Data
{
    int longtitude;
};

struct Data* WritingData()
{
    struct Data *arr = (struct Data*)malloc(rows* cols* sizeof(struct Data));

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
         scanf("%d",&(arr + i*cols+ j)->longtitude);
    
    free(arr);
    return(arr);
}

int main()
{
    struct Data *arr = WritingData();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
    printf(" %d ", (arr + i*cols+ j)->longtitude);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate memory for your array and populate it, but then you free the memory before returning the pointer from the function.

Once allocated memory is freed it is no longer accessible.  Attempting to access memory that has been freed triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Don't call `free` until after you're done using it, in this case at the end of `main`.